# How to make Robot Framework Data Driven?

Tags: robotframework

In a test case I am able to read a csv file by following code

```
${value} =   read_csv_file    TestData.csv
   Set Test Variable    ${value}
   log   ${value}
```

But now the question comes why my test case will repeat for different data. Although if I want to repeat any step I can use `for` loop but I want to repeat this for entire test suite.

```
:FOR  ${newvalue}   in   @{value}
  \       Select Product   @{newvalue}[0]
```

`Templates` are not preferred because they make the framework totally `data-driven` and also they have certain limitation.

Comment: Can you please format any code blocks? Also I'm not very clear on what you want to do, what is wrong with templates exactly?  You may be familiar with this already but I'd take a closer look - http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#data-driven-style

Comment: Using templates does not necessarily make the entire framework totally data-driven. You can use `[Template]` at the test case level. Then only that test case will be data-driven.

Answer (score 1):

As you don't want to use templates, you can also use `keyword-driven` approach of robot framework.
You need to create a robot resource file, define your keyword and call it where you want this particular code in your robot test suite.

```
***keywords***
Read and display
    [Argument]    ${filename}
    ${value} =   read_csv_file    ${filename}
    Set Test Variable    ${value}
    log   ${value}
```